# Math Menu Loop return

Tags: python-3.x, return

The function will not return option, I ran the code multiple times and cannot spot the error. See if you guys can spot it out I've looked online everywhere.

```
def menu():
    print("1. Addition")
    print("2. Subtraction")
    print("3. Multiplication")
    print("4. Division")
    
    
def main(option):
    option = input("Enter your selection: ")
    
    while option != 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
        count = 0 #controls how many menu() is printed
        print(menu(), count)
        count = +1
        option = input("Enter your selection: ")
        return option
        
    
main()
```

Console Output

```
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'option'
```

Comment: you define main(option) but you're not passing an 'option" argument through main.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
menu()

choice = int(input("Enter input: ")) # get user input and cast it to int

main(choice) # requires a number to be passed to it
```

Or you can modify main to not take options:

```
def main(): # it no longer takes a parameter
    option = input("Enter your selection: ")
    
    while option != 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
        count = 0 #controls how many menu() is printed
        print(menu(), count)
        count = +1
        option = input("Enter your selection: ")
        return option
        
    
main() # this will work now
```

Answer (score 0):

you called a function main without calling passing in an argument.

Your function main is a function that takes in a variable option